# AngularJS watch model value if model is not null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

Simple question here.
I have this watch:

```
// Watch our model
$scope.$watch(function () {

    // Watch our team name
    return self.model.team.data.name;
}, function (name) {

    console.log(name);

    // if we have a name
    if (name) {

        // Store our model in the session
        sessionStorage.designer = angular.toJson(self.model);
    }
});
```

The team model is pull in from the database as a promise (hence the data) so when the watch first fires **self.model.team** has not been set so it is null.
How can I get my watch to either wait until it has been set or add a check into the return function of the watch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic here - if one of the variables you are accessing could be `null`/`undefined`, then you cannot get its property if it's `null`/`undefined`. So, you have to guard against that:

```
$scope.$watch(
  function(){
    return (self.model.team && self.model.team.data.name) || undefined;
  }, 
  function(v){
    // ...
  });
```

The only "magic" is when you "$watch" for expressions, but the expressions need to be exposed on the scope. So, you could do:

```
$scope.model = self.model;
$scope.$watch("model.team.data.name", function(v){
  // ...
});
```

But, really, you have to ask yourself why you need a `$watch` here to begin with. It seems to me that you are getting the `team` asynchronously once - it does not look like it will change except by maybe another async call. So, just handle that when you receive the data without the `$watch`:

```
someSvc.getTeam() // I made an assumption about a service that pulls the data from db
  .then(function(team){
     var name = team.data.name;

     // if we have a name
     if (name) {
        // Store our model in the session
        sessionStorage.designer = angular.toJson(self.model);
     }
  });
```

An unnecessary `$watch` is expensive - it is evaluated on every digest cycle, so, it's best to reduce the number of $watchers.

Comment: actually, it was not the get team function where I am trying to update the session. I was updating after every action (choosing colours, selecting garments etc) but there was on area where this was working and that was a 2 way binding on a text box. So that is why I put the watch there. Then I read an article explaining that perhaps using watches in controllers is a bad idea and gave another option. So now I am using ng-change on my textbox and calling a function called self.saveSession instead. So, now I have done that this question is just for reference now.

Answer (score 2):

Use a watch expression instead of a function. This will catch any errors with missing objects and return `undefined`.

```
// Watch our model
$scope.$watch('self.model.team.data.name', function (name) {

    console.log(name);

    // if we have a name
    if (name) {

        // Store our model in the session
        sessionStorage.designer = angular.toJson(self.model);
    }
});
```

Comment: by default should I use an expression rather than a function? I always use the function because I have had issues in the past where it appears the watch wasn't working.

Comment: Is there a reason you omitted the self from self.model.team.data.name?

Comment: you're right, i just assumed it was on the scope. I tend to use expressions, but you could do checks for the objects existing instead if you wanted.

Comment: unfortunately the expression one still doesn't work even with the "self" added. No idea why.
Can you give an example of a check for the object existing?